# Insert and Delete - Run in Order

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to run several statements one after the other, but to only execute the next when the previous has finished running?

I have a statement that copies data from one db into an archive data. 
It then deletes the data from the "live" db once it's been copied.

If I execute each part of the below query separately, it works fine. 
If I execute the whole thing as one statement, it errors, presumably because it's trying to delete from faults before it's finished copying the data from the 
`INSERT` of the statement above.

```
--- Copies data from Faults into Archive DB
INSERT INTO Faults 
SELECT *
FROM OriginalDB.dbo.Faults
where Flastactiondate < '2012-09-30'

-- Deletes archived faults from live db
Delete  from OriginalDB.dbo.Faults
where OriginalDB.dbo.Faults.Faultid in (select FaultID from ArchiveDB.dbo.Faults)



-- Copies data from actions into archiveTB
Insert Into Actions
select * 
from OriginalDB.dbo.ACTIONS
where OriginalDB.dbo.ACTIONS.Faultid in (select FaultID from ArchiveDB.dbo.Faults)

-- Deletes archived actions form live db
delete 
from OriginalDB.dbo.ACTIONS
where OriginalDB.dbo.ACTIONS.Faultid in (select FaultID from ArchiveDB.dbo.Faults)
```

Ideally I want to be able to start this, and leave it running overnight, without having to manually run each statement.

Comment: Your "presumably" is incorrect. SQL statements execute in a perfectly sequential manner. What error are you getting? Is anything else running while you're doing this that could modify the tables or keep records locked?

Comment: what is the error you're receiving?

Comment: I assume, you are executing them in the Server Management Studio. Insert a GO between your statements.

Comment: My guess is that this has more to do with transactions.  When you execute the whole thing at once it wraps everything in a transaction and nothing is committed until the last delete occurs.  When you run each query separately you are in effect creating multiple transactions that commit within each block.  So if subsequent queries relied on data being inserted into some other table unless you used a (nolock) hint on your dependent queries that data that you just inserted would not be there until the last delete had been performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I commented earlier:

```
--- Copies data from Faults into Archive DB
INSERT INTO Faults SELECT *
FROM OriginalDB.dbo.Faults
where Flastactiondate < '2012-09-30'

GO

-- Deletes archived faults from live db
Delete  from OriginalDB.dbo.Faults
where OriginalDB.dbo.Faults.Faultid in (select FaultID from        ArchiveDB.dbo.Faults)

GO

-- Copies data from actions into archiveTB
Insert Into Actions select * 
from OriginalDB.dbo.ACTIONS
where OriginalDB.dbo.ACTIONS.Faultid in (select FaultID from    ArchiveDB.dbo.Faults)

GO

-- Deletes archived actions form live db
delete from OriginalDB.dbo.ACTIONS
where OriginalDB.dbo.ACTIONS.Faultid in (select FaultID from ArchiveDB.dbo.Faults)

GO
```

Comment: If you are using this queries in ADO.Net you should use semicolon ";" between each query.

Comment: Also, in case of stored procedure you can not use go. I think OP has some different issue.